# vba macro to compare two columns in excel?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to compare `QTY` and `UID` in one sheet (`Shipment`) to another sheet (`Record`). I am trying to compare if the `UID` is equal then compare the `QTY`, if the `QTY` is equal then output **"Complete"** else **"Incomplete"** besides the record in the `Record` sheet.

**Sheet `Record`**

```
UID qty Shipped
234 2   incomplete
335 5   
453 6   
664 3   complete
787 13
```

**Sheet `Shipment`**

```
UID qty
664 3
234 1
```

Comment: one thing that you need to consider: you have to update "Record" after a partial shipment, otherwise, the rest of the shipment will also be considered "incomplete"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have both the value and a formula in the same cell.
You will need VBA for what you are trying to achieve.

Try this..

```
Sub GetQtyStatus()
Dim sws As Worksheet, dws As Worksheet
Dim Rng As Range, Cell As Range
Dim lr As Long, r As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set sws = Sheets("Shipment")
Set dws = Sheets("Record")
lr = dws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set Rng = dws.Range("A2:A" & lr)

For Each Cell In Rng
    If Application.CountIf(sws.Columns(1), Cell.Value) > 0 Then
        r = Application.Match(Cell.Value, sws.Columns(1), 0)
        If Cell.Offset(0, 1) = sws.Cells(r, 2) Then
            Cell.Offset(0, 2) = "Complete"
        Else
            Cell.Offset(0, 2) = "Incomplete"
        End If
    End If
Next Cell

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

**How to implement the code:**

1. Open your workbook and press Alt + F11 to open VB Editor.
2. On VB Editor --> Insert --> Module and paste the code give above into the opened code window.
3. Close VB Editor and save your workbook as Macro-Enabled Workbook.

**How to run the code:**

1. Press Alt + F8 to open Macro window.
2. Choose the macro GetQtyStatus and click on Run.

The code assumes that there are two sheets called Record and Shipment in the workbook and UID and Qty are listed in column A and B respectively on both the sheets.

Comment: Thank you so much this is exactly what i am looking for!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your Sheet `Shipment` is as follows

[image]

Then in `Cell C2` of Sheet `Record` enter the following formula

```
=IFERROR(IF(INDEX($A$2:$A$6,MATCH(1,(A2=Shipment!$A$2:$A$3)*1,0)),IFERROR(IF(INDEX($A$2:$A$6,MATCH(1,(B2=Shipment!$B$2:$B$3)*1,0)),"Complete"),"Incomplete"),""),"")
```

This is an array formula so commit it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. Drag/Copy down as required.See image for reference.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer however it isnt exactly what i am looking for, the formula will replace previous shipped comments if the UID dont match

Answer (score 1):

A non Array formula that allows full column references and entered as normal:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2,Shipment!A:A,0)),IF(COUNTIFS(Shipment!A:A,A2,Shipment!B:B,B2),"Complete","Imcomplete"),"")
```

[image]

---

Or this shorter version:

```
=IFERROR(IF(INDEX(Shipment!B:B,MATCH(A2,Shipment!A:A,0)) = B2,"Complete","Imcomplete"),"")
```

Comment: Thank you for the formula however, is there anyone way to have a formula that if the UID dont match then do nothing as some UIDs will have comment s from previous weeks and the formula will replace the comments with a blank? (when i say comment i mean "Complete" "incomplete")

Comment: Yes you will need vba then.  Stack Overflow is not a code for me site.  I just answered to give a better alternative to an array formula.